# Ikea Stockaryd wood treatment oil

Tags: finishing

I have the Ikea Karlby countertop, which is a walnut veneer - can you use the Stockaryd oil to help treat and waterproof the countertop??

Can't find anywhere on Ikea that says that this product can be used for that.

Comment: "**Product details**
This wood treatment oil penetrates deeply into the wood to enhance the wood feel and water resistance, while also protecting the surface and providing a shiny finish.The long shelf life makes it easier for you to care for your furniture and **wooden countertops** at regular intervals."

Comment: It's just some sort of boiled linseed oil and "tung" oil (whatever that is these days). So any Q&A regarding either of these will probably have any other info you need.

Comment: The Karlby is already finished as supplied so it isn't necessary to add finish at this stage, but you can if you want to. Despite what Ikea claim it won't add much in the way of protection, although it may improve the appearance — giving it more of a 'finished wood' look, but my recollection of the Karlbys in the flesh is that they look fine as-is.

Answer (score 2):

It says this right in the Product Details for the Karlby worktops, under **Materials & care**:

*To ensure that your worktop ages gracefully, treat it regularly with STOCKARYD wood treatment oil; it gives the surface a beautiful sheen, protects the wood and prolongs the life of the worktop.*

A note on the application guidelines for the Stockaryd: the wording doesn't emphasise clearly that after the second coat any unabsorbed oil must again be wiped off, which is a vital step in the application of all oil finishes of this type. If you leave *any* excess on the surface it will 'dry' but it will never be hard, and will leave the surface gummy or sticky.